# modify variable value in codeigniter model

Tags: php, oop

I have controller and model. i am modifying a variable value in a model, but it doesn't reflect in controller, I am not that much expert in OOP.

```
// controller class structure
class Leads_import extends CI_Controller {

public $total = 0;

  public function import(){
   $this->xml_model->imsert();
   echo $this->total; 
  }
}

// model class structure
class xml_model extends CI_Model {

   public function insert(){
      this->total = 10; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// controller class structure
class Leads_import extends CI_Controller {

public $total = 0;

  public function import(){
   $this->total = $this->xml_model->imsert();
  }
}
```

Model:

```
// model class structure
class xml_model extends CI_Model {

   public function insert(){
      return 10; 
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i am performing other things in "insert" function and returning something else from that funciton so i cant write this line "$this->total = $this->xml_model->insert()" because insert function does many things, If you dont understand please let me know so i can show u complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the `$total` of `xml_model` or have it update the `$total` of `Leads_import`. You're reading the wrong variable in the controller, it never gets updated.

Here's what I suggest without knowing what you're really trying to do:

```
class Leads_import extends CI_Controller {
   public $total = 0;
   public function import(){
     $this->xml_model->insert();
     // Read xml_model total and assign to Leads_import total
     $this->total = $this->xml_model->total; 
     echo $this->total; 
  }
}

class xml_model extends CI_Model {
   public $total = 0;
   public function insert(){
      $this->total = 10; // update xml_model total
   }
}
```